# Shuffle large data file(s) in mapreduce

Tags: java, algorithm, mapreduce

Let's say I have a file of several billion lines and the size is 500G to 1T. How can I produce a new file with the same lines, but randomly shuffle the lines? The shuffle should be completely random if can be achieved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a mapper that maps a `GUID` to your line. The following Hadoop mapper illustrates the logic:

```
public class ShuffleMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {
  @Override
  protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    context.write(new Text(UUID.randomUUID().toString()), value);
  }
}
```

In the reducer, you just collect the lines (values). This can be done using a single reducer, or if you face resource issues (e.g. a local disk fills up) you can split multiple reducers and then just `concat` lines from the commandline.

**Note:** This doesn't necessarily gives an unbiased shuffle like Fisher-Yates does, but this solution easier to implement and quite fast.

Comment: Clever. I'd add a link to this article on random sampling. It could be used to do a shuffle: http://had00b.blogspot.com/2013/07/random-subset-in-mapreduce.html

Comment: One question: does the number of reducers have any influence on the randomness?

Comment: @JackLei it shouldn't, at least no influence comes into my mind. The only influence on the randomness should be caused by the UUID algorithm, so just look how "random" it is (it is likely time dependend, thus mappers running at the same time might cause the same sequence- although this is also relatively unlikely to happen).